# Add non arc library in arc enabled project iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, static-libraries

I have going through some issues lately while implementing sound processing library from:

http://www.izotope.com/tech/izomobile/djfx.asp

Problem which I think is with my implementation which is ARC enabled and library is non arc C++ implementation. I have tried adding -fno-objc-arc for files using that library and also tried changing viewcontrollers extensions to .mm instead of .m. Please have a look at images attached and let me know if anyone else faced this issue.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

You can download sample project link from: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljvnevkwkyplp2k/SoundEffects_ARC.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your code needs to link with C++ standard library. Change these target build settings in your project and check if it works,

```
Apple LLVM compiler language-> C++ language dialect-> Compiler default
Apple LLVM compiler language-> C++ standard library-> Compiler default
```

[image]

Also, the warning on top indicates that your library `libFunFX.a` is not built for `i386` i.e. the iPhone simulator. To make sure here's what you can try.

Open terminal, goto the folder which contains the library and use this command

```
lipo -info libFunFX.a ↵
//Output: 
Architectures in the fat file: libFunFX.a are: armv7 i386
```

If it lists out i386 then no worries, else you need to communicate the owner to send you a FAT file containing slices for both the device (armv7/armv7s) and simulator(i386).

---

**EDIT**

I see there are two libraries in your project, combine both to create a single FAT file with following command.

```
lipo -create libFunFX.a libFunFXSim.a -output libFunFX_Univ.a
```

So now if you check,

```
lipo -info libFunFX_Univ.a 
//Output 
Architectures in the fat file: libFunFX_Univ.a are: armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) i386
```

Changes in project files

- Change `AppDelegate.m` to `AppDelegate.mm`
- Change ViewController.m to `ViewController.mm`
- Add and link the above created `libFunFX_Univ.a` file instead of two separate .a files.
- Mark files `-fno-objc-arc` as below image

[image]

Making these changes I was able to build your project successfully for simulator. I am not sure if you really want to use ARC because lot of the files are marked for manual memory management. In that case it would be easier to just do manual memory management for entire project. Just a suggestion!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is what I got in terminal:
<<
accounts002:SoundEffects_ARC awais$ lipo -info libFunFX.a

Architectures in the fat file: libFunFX.a are: armv7 (cputype (12) cpusubtype (11)) 
>>
I didn't get it. Kinda newbee

Comment: @AwaisTariq Okay, `(cputype (12) cpusubtype (11))` is armv7s. So your library does not contain slice for i386. So you need to ask the owner of the lib to send FAT file containing i386 as well. Meanwhile you can try building this code for device.

Comment: Thanks let me try ^_^

Comment: I have provided sample project. See if you can help me out in resolving this issue?

Comment: @AwaisTariq I was able to build the project for simulator successfully with few changes. I will add them in my edited answer.

Comment: thanks alot :)
I was also able to run sample project. Now in my real application I am facing https://www.dropbox.com/s/sebrh7uoecub8wk/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-20%20at%2012.43.57%20PM.png this type of issues. Don't know whats wrong with it. I have made changes you listed above. Once again thanks alot for your time.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you in chat.

Comment: Thats okay, you need to click on the > next to the first error in top file. That list will show where all the cpp header is included. In that list if there is any .m file you should change it to .mm. The errors are because your compiler considers cpp code as ObjC when .m is file extension.

Comment: there is a long list of files.. find it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9unevy9ixwpqxq0/Screen%20Shot%202013-09-20%20at%202.46.27%20PM.png

Do I need to change all the files to .mm.

Comment: @AwaisTariq Seems just one file in all those errors `SkipImageViewController.m`. Change that to .mm and rebuild.

Comment: Hello @Amar. Can we have a chat?

Answer (score 3):

I just put basic step here, follow it **or** compare with your step which already done by you.

```
  Select Project Form Project Manager
      |
      | 
      Targets
           |
           |
         Build Phases
              |
              |
            Compile Sources
                    |
                    |
                Select File that you Want to crate as ARC. (You can also Select Multiple File name from here)
                            |
                            |
                        Press "ENTER" key
                               |
                               |
                          Popup Box/Window is displayed 
                                   |
                                   |
                                Write here - '-fno-objc-arc'
                                        |
                                        |
                                    And again Press 'ENTER' key.


Your selected file is being ARC.
```

Comment: Project is ARC enabled I want to add non arc library. Also I have tried this process. :S

Comment: Rather than using `-fno-objc-arc` isn't it better to simply uncheck the *Automatic Reference Counting* setting?

Answer (score 1):

Those linker errors have nothing to do with ARC, it's simply that the C++ runtime library has not been configured.

Now you have two choices; the old `libstdc++` or the new `libc++` and I cannot tell from the error messages which ones you should use, so you will have to experiment:

[image]

Also it looks like `.../SoundsEffects_ARC.a` has not been compiled for the iPhone Simulator (missing architecture i386 is the clue here).  Easiest way to solve that, if you have the source, is to create an Xcode Workspace and include that project in the workspace and configured dependencies and then Xcode will build it for the iPhone Simulator as-and-when required.  If you don't have the source then you are out of luck and need a fat version of the archive which does include the i386 arch code.

Comment: I have provided sample project. See if you can help me out in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I Think this error is not arc - non arc issue . This is frame work / lib link error

check the you have integrate all frame works

Comment: I have, as I made a sample project like same but without using ARC. It worked fine.

Comment: check the Third party lib is only work on non arc because,may be lib internal files only using arc mode , I think t

Comment: I think Third party providing non arc lib for that check once